# How to use jquery in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

Using jquery, how can you search through a string of html code, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert($('#t','<span id="t">d</span>').html());
</script>
```

I expect to get `d` in the alert, but I get undefined...

Does anyone know how to do this?

Actually I use an ajax request to get an html string of the page. If I then try to paste the string in some tag, then the current page gets all messed up. So I wanted to search through the given string.

Comment: you have the element. So, this should work `alert($('<span id="t">d</span>').html());`. But I am not sure whether this is good or not.

Comment: Your test case is so specialized as to be absurd. What real problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This which works, makes NO sense to do so I will NOT post it as an answer `alert($('<span id="t">d</span>').html());`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yup indeed. makes no sense.

Comment: Hence why I down voted the question and admit to doing so.

Answer (score 3):

The *context* parameter is the context **within** which jQuery will search. I.e. it will look at child elements of that context but not at the context itself. This works:

```
alert($('#t','<span><span id="t">d</span></span>').html());
```

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do there though. You already have the element, no need to search for it. This example will probably never be applied to any real world problem.

Comment: I explain why I did this in the post under.

Comment: Yes, it will have to be wrapped in something or the OP will have to clarify.  +1 for the wrapper of a really, in my opinion bad question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using (or can use, as seems to be the case) [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to fetch the contents into for example element `#target`:

```
$( '#target' ).load( 'myfile.html #t' );
```

This will fetch only the element `#t` inside myfile.html.

If for some reason you can't use `.load()`, as a last resort you can create jQuery objects from the response and use it to search for the content:

```
$.ajax( 'myfile.html' ).done( function( data ) {
    $( data ).find( '#t' ).appendTo( '#target' );
});
```

Use `.filter()` instead of `.find()` if `#t` is a top-level element in the returned data.